# Guardar estado e conteúdo da última aba clicada

Tags: jquery

Tenho uma página com algumas abas que carregam um conteúdo através do recurso .load, eu gostaria que após retornar a esta página a última aba clicada continue marcada e o conteúdo chamado via load continue o mesmo. Como posso fazer isso?

Exemplo do código aplicado:

```js
jQuery("containerAbas span").click(function({
jQuery(this).removeClass("abaInativa").addClass("abaAtiva").siblings("span").addClass("abaInativa");
jQuery("#carregar").css("display","none").fadeIn("slow").load("pagina.html")
});
```

```css
.abaAtiva{
  margin:0 0.5% 0 0;
  padding:10px 1% 0 1%;
  height:35px;
  background:#ff5800;
  float:left;
  color:#fff;
}

.abaInativa{
  margin:0 0.5% 0 0;
  padding:10px 1% 0 1%;
  height:35px;
  background:#c6c5c5;
  color:#333;
  float:left;
}
```

```html
<div class="containerAbas">
  <span id="aba1" class="abaAtiva">item 1</span>
  <span id="aba2" class="abaInativa">item 2</span>
</div>
```

Comment: você já tentou fazer algo ? tem algum código para complementar sua pergunta?

Comment: Desculpe não consegui compreender o que desejas, de uma olhada em [como fazer uma boa pergunta?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , e tente adicionar mais detalhes.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar cookies para isso.
Com jQuery pode-se fazer uso do plugin [JQUERY COOKIE](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

Coloque um evento onclik para que armazene uma informação ao clicar a aba.

ex:

```
jQuery.cookie("ABA", "1");
```

No evento onload utilize

```
var x = jQuery.cookie("ABA");
```

Para saber qual foi a ultima aba a ser clicada.

Ajustando ao seu código ficaria

```
<script src="https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/src/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="containerAbas">
  <span id="aba1" class="abaAtiva">item 1</span>
  <span id="aba2" class="abaInativa">item 2</span>
</div>

jQuery(".containerAbas span").click(function(){
        jQuery(this).removeClass("abaInativa").addClass("abaAtiva").siblings("span").addClass("abaInativa");
        jQuery.cookie("ultima_aba_aberta", jQuery(this).attr("id"), { expires: 30 }); // marcando a aba clicada

    jQuery("#carregar").css("display","none").fadeIn("slow").load("pagina.html")
    });
jQuery(function() {
    var ultima_aba = jQuery.cookie("ultima_aba_aberta");
    if (ultima_aba != null) {
        jQuery("#" + ultima_aba).trigger("click");  
    }

});
```

Comment: Desculpe, não entendi, pode por favor exemplificar?

Comment: editei a resposta incluindo os código para que teste.

Comment: Marcos, tem dois tipos de inserção de código no editor aqui do Stack, os Snippets Executáveis são tipo JSFiddle, aqui no caso tinha que ser um bloco de código simples. Confira: [Apresentando: JS, CSS e HTML executáveis!](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2115/201) e [Como devemos formatar perguntas e respostas?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1084/201)

Comment: jQuery.coockie é um plugin, correto?

Comment: Sim, esqueci de adicionar na resposta. Agora está lá.
@brasofilo Removi os snippets

Comment: Valeu Marcos! Obrigado